# Can't get aspnet.core server route to load with default path, when using Angular

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-routing

I want all calls that are not caught by any server side routes to load my spa. So in my `startup.cs` file I have the following

```
// routes
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    // default goes to Home, and angular will deal with client side routing     
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{*url}",
        defaults: new { controller = "home", action = "index" });
});
```

I then have a server page that I want to load without adding the word "index" to the path, so it should load the index view when I go to `http://localhost:5000/serverRoute` but it always tries to load my spa. If however I change the URL to `http://localhost:5000/serverRoute/index` then the server page loads.

My ASP.net core controller looks like so

```
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
public class ServerRouteController : Controller
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Load default index view
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

What am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `[Route("[controller]/[action]")]`? Why does a Controller have an action parameter?

Answer (score 0):

The controller action token in the route template is not optional, which is why is does not match when not present in the URL.

```
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
public class ServerRouteController : Controller {
    /// <summary>
    /// Load default index view
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [Route("")]         //Match /ServerRoute
    [Route("[action]")] //Match /ServerRoute/Index
    public IActionResult Index() {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Reference [Routing to Controller Actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)